Raising NotImplementedError in abstract methods
While studying the source code of the numbers.py module from build-in lib, I came across two variants of @abstractmethod (with and without the NotImplementedError raise). Example:
class Complex(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __complex__(self):
        """Return a builtin complex instance. Called for complex(self)."""

    @abstractmethod
    def __neg__(self):
        """-self"""
        raise NotImplementedError

Next, I created a child class:
class MyComplex(Complex):
    def __complex__(self):
        return complex(1, 1)
    
    def __neg__(self):
        return complex(-1, -1)

After playing with this code for a bit, I found only one difference:
>>> c = MyComplex()
>>> Complex.__complex__(c)
>>> Complex.__neg__(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/maskalev/dev/foo/bar.py", line 15, in __neg__
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

when calling the __complex__() method, None is returned, and when calling __neg__(), an exception is raised (which, in fact, is described in the code).
So I have some questions:

Is this the only difference?
Why is NotImplementedError raising not used in the first case, but used in the second? (Isn't it better to do it uniformly?)
What is the best practice? (I think it's better to raise an exception explicitly, but maybe I don't see the whole picture.)


What is the point of calling Complex.__neg__ and not MyComplex.__neg__? I believe that __neg__ in general is the unary minus operator, so -c should call it and it should call the right one, too.

It's just an example. I'm not interested in this particular class or method but in the general approach.
